# Error PHP get_result?

Tags: get, fetch

As get_result function is available on **PHP 5 >= 5.3.0**, *PHP 7* is there anybody knows hot to change this part of codes?
`$user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc()`;

Since the host that i currenlty use is php 5.1 and it doesn't have mysqlInd driver i encounter some errors.

```
public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");

    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        $stmt->close();

        // verifying user password
        $salt = $user['salt'];
        $encrypted_password = $user['encrypted_password'];
        $hash = $this->checkhashSSHA($salt, $password);
        // check for password equality
        if ($encrypted_password == $hash) {
            // user authentication details are correct
            return $user;
        }
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you tell us more clearly what result you are expecting, what result you are actually getting? What are the error messages you are seeing?

Comment: Here is the error :

all to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in

I would like to change this part of code with other function to return $user